# How to completely uninstall a package (including all extra files that came with it) using yum (or rpm)?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm

When I do `yum remove`, it sometimes keeps a package's configuration files.

Is there anyway to remove a package completely, without keeping any file that belonged to the package?

I am running CentOS.

Comment: Can you provide an example of configuration files are left after yum remove?

Comment: ~/.mozilla left by firefox, for example

Comment: ~/.mozilla is created only when you run the firefox program. It is not created by the firefox package. Run the command `rpm -qf ~/.mozilla` and it will report that that file is not part of any package.

Comment: @ZaSter : When I removed quagga package it kept all its config files in /etc/quagga (Files like zebra.conf, ospfd.conf, bgpd.conf) which should have been removed along with package itself. If it is by design to keep them, then please provide a command that will also remove the configuration files.

Comment: @TusharG That's correct. For RPM packages that contain declared configuration files, `yum remove` does not remove those files.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check the `Deleting packages with yum` section in the [HOW TO](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/yum_HOWTO/yum_HOWTO/yum_HOWTO-10.html)

There says:

In any event, the command syntax for package removal is:

```
   # yum remove package1 [package2 package3...]
```

As noted above, it removes package1 and all packages in the dependency tree that depend on package1, possibly irreversibly as far as configuration data is concerned.

As a quick way you can try:

```
yum remove package
yum install package
```

Also [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/41502/yum-equivalent-of-apt-get-purge) is an interesting `for`. And the question can help you.

The one that keeps configs in a backup is `rpm -e`

What you can do is find out what is in a rpm using:

```
 rpm -ql packagename
```

or

```
rpm -qlp packagename if the package is not yet installed.
```

then, you can manually make the modifications you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess it is probably impossible to remove all files that ever came with a package... but still your recommendation is helpful.

Comment: doesn't work on RHEL7. `/etc/sysconfig/<package>` file is still there.

Comment: @erikbstack, yeah this is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
rpm -e xxx.rpm && rpm -ivh --replacefiles xxx.rpm
```

This in effect replaces the old configs kept after "erasing"
Must be a way to do this with yum and dnf

Answer (score 0):

With root privileges, use

```
yum remove -y vsftpd
```